# Remove everything before the first forward slash in the url

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I need to remove everything before the third forward using regex so that for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask becomes /questions/ask I'm not the greatest when it comes to regular expressions so your help would be much appreciated.

This is what I have so far https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/498

The code I currently have is but want to use regex:

```
url.substring(url.indexOf('\/') + 3)
```

Comment: `url.indexOf('\/') + 3` wouldn't remove everything before the third / anyway - and your regex101 is not in javascript mode either

Comment: Try `s = s.replace(/^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}/, '/')` or check this: https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the questions asks for regex but the need is unclear - if all you *need* is the path name there are better tools in the toolbox (for anybody not working on a homework exercise).

```js
const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
console.log(new URL(url).pathname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`(?<=.*\/.*\/.*\/).+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFoCfw/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=` - its positive look behind, in any position that's pattern inside it is find matching start from this position to forward.
- `.*\/.*\/.*\/` - it is used inside the positive look behind, it cause matching start after the position that behind that position is 3 forward slashes
- `.+` - match one or more of from anything

**Edit**:
From @JaromandaX's comment, this can also be used (and honestly I think it more readable and simper):

`(?<=(?:.*?\/){3}).+`

Comment: Please can you explain what the regex is doing?

Comment: why not `(?<=(?:.*?\/){3}).+`

Comment: @nless I edited my answer and add an explanation, hope this can help you

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it can be used as well